# Elasticsearch - Group by not working for more than 1 word which contains space in between

Tags: elasticsearch

I have be working for more than 3 days in this and tried many forums to fix this but still not possible.

Also I am new to Elasticsearch as this is our first project to implement.

For me Create New Index and Get the Index has been working fine. Now i want to get the search results with "group by" like in sql.

Below scripts are what i am using now

Step 1 :
I have Installed Elasticsearch 2.0 in Ubuntu 14.04. I able to create new Index using below code. Also i am using PHP to call ES

```
$hosts = array('our ip address:9200');
$client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts($hosts)->build();
$index = "IndexName";
$params['index'] = $index;
$params['type'] = 'xyz';
$params['body']["id"] = "1";
$params['body']["title"] = "PHP Developer";
$params['body']["location"] = "United States";
$client->index($params);
```

once the above code runs Index successfully created.

Step 2 :
Able to look into the created Index using below link

```
`http://our ip address:9200/IndexName/_search?q=PHP&pretty

{
"took" : 30,
"timed_out" : false,
"_shards" : {
"total" : 5,
"successful" : 5,
"failed" : 0
},
"hits" : {
"total" : 3,
"max_score" : 0.8968174,
"hits" : [ {
"_index" : "IndexName",
"_type" : "xyz",
"_id" : "1545680",
"_score" : 0.8968174,
"_source":{"id":"1545680","title":"PHP Developer","location":"United States"}
}, {
"_index" : "IndexName",
"_type" : "xyz",
"_id" : "1539771",
"_score" : 0.753807,
"_source":{"id":"1539771","title":"PHP Team Lead","location":"United States"}
}, {
"_index" : "IndexName",
"_type" : "xyz",
"_id" : "1539772",
"_score" : 0.253807,
"_source":{"id":"1539772","title":"PHP Lead","location":"India"}
}
....
```

Step 3: Now i want to add group by using below code
So i added the below mapping while creating new Index

```
$params['body']['mappings']['xyz']['properties']['location'] = array('type' => 'string','fields' => array("untouched" => array('type' => 'string','index' => 'not_analyzed')));
```

Step 4: I use below code for group by

```
$params['index'] = "IndexName";
$params['type']  = 'xyz';
$params['body']['query']['query_string'] = array("query" => "PHP","default_operator" => "AND" ,"fields" => array("title"));
$params['body']["aggs"] =  array("location" => array("terms" => array("field" => "location.untouched")));
$response = $client->search($params);
```

Step 5: The response below i get

```
[aggregations] => Array
(
[location] => Array
(
[doc_count_error_upper_bound] => 0
[sum_other_doc_count] => 0
[buckets] => Array
(
)
)
)
```

Step 6: I removed .untounched from aggs

```
$params['body']["aggs"] = array("location" => array("terms" => array("field" => "location")));
```

I got the below response

```
[aggregations] => Array
(
[location] => Array
(
[doc_count_error_upper_bound] => 0
[sum_other_doc_count] => 0
[buckets] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[key] => united
[doc_count] => 2
)
[1] => Array
(
[key] => india
[doc_count] => 1
)
[2] => Array
(
[key] => states
[doc_count] => 2
)
)
)
)
```

From the step 6 output i got almost group by working but the problem is the key get separated count.

How to fix this issue?

is there any setting need to changed?

Help me to fix this issue

```
Below array is the response from the Search function
Array
(
    [took] => 278
    [timed_out] => 
    [_shards] => Array
        (
            [total] => 20
            [successful] => 20
            [failed] => 0
        )

    [hits] => Array
        (
            [total] => 2
            [max_score] => 0.30436125
            [hits] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => MY-INDEX-NAME
                            [_type] => MY-INDEX-TYPE
                            [_id] => 1550713
                            [_score] => 0.30436125
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [mappings] => Array
                                        (
                                            [job] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [properties] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [location] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [type] => string
                                                                    [fields] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [untouched] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [type] => string
                                                                                    [index] => not_analyzed
                                                                                )

                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [id] => 1550713
                                    [jobrole] => 
Web Developer\\
                                    [description] => 
 tested\\
                                    [location] => United Arab Emirates
                                    [city] => 
Abu Dhabi\\


                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => MY-INDEX-NAME
                            [_type] => MY-INDEX-TYPE
                            [_id] => 1550712
                            [_score] => 0.2660934
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [mappings] => Array
                                        (
                                            [job] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [properties] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [location] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [type] => string
                                                                    [fields] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [untouched] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [type] => string
                                                                                    [index] => not_analyzed
                                                                                )

                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [id] => 1550712
                                    [jobrole] => 
PHP Developer\\
                                    [description] => 
 tested\\
                                    [location] => Australia
                                    [city] => 
Aberdeen\\


                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [aggregations] => Array
        (
            [location] => Array
                (
                    [doc_count_error_upper_bound] => 0
                    [sum_other_doc_count] => 0
                    [buckets] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => arab
                                    [doc_count] => 1
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => australia
                                    [doc_count] => 1
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => emirates
                                    [doc_count] => 1
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => united
                                    [doc_count] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Thanks
Aravin

Comment: Location should be not_analyzed. Also, seems like u tried to change mapping after indexing docs. Mapping should be created first and then u should index hmthe docs. Also, if you are looking for grouping by exact values, you should map it as not_analyzed.

Comment: @rahulroc ye i already removed the indexing and reindex the docs. Also if you note that the location field also not_analyzed


$params['body']['mappings']['xyz']['properties']['location'] = array('type' => 'string','fields' => array("untouched" => array('type' => 'string','index' => 'not_analyzed')));

Comment: I am not aware with PHP syntax, but it seems like 'location' is an array of type string and a nested field untouched (string, not_analyzed). To me, location itself is analyzed but location.untouched is not. If you can post the json version of the same, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Please check my json data mentioned above

Comment: Please share the output of curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/<INDEX_NAME>/_mapping/<INDEX_TYPE>'

Comment: I managed to fix this mapping issue , now i am facing analyzer issue where the analyzer is not working. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/group-by-not-working-for-more-than-1-word-which-contains-space-in-between/45744